# JavaScript, the top of the prototype chain is null, how to prove it by code?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-chain

Javascript checks for the property on `object.prototype`, `object.prototype.prototype`, and so on until it hits `null`. At that point, Javascript returns `undefined`.
But how to prove the top of prototype chain is `null` rather than `undefined`?

Comment: What do you mean by "prove"? The language is designed so that prototype chains always end with `null`, and so that `undefined` is not a valid value for an object's prototype, so no runtime proof is needed.

Comment: ...`undefined` will never be returned due to an `undefined` prototype being encountered, because that's impossible. However, `undefined` may be returned if the matching property is located with the *value* of `undefined` assigned to it.

Comment: Note that the `.prototype` property doesn't give you the object's prototype, and is `undefined` for non-function objects (unless you explicitly create such a property, but that doesn't affect the prototype chain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate with a while loop, and use [Object#getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to get the prototype of the current object:

```js
let object = {};

while(object = Object.getPrototypeOf(object)) {}

console.log(object);
```

Comment: But why would you ever do this in practice? The OP is certainly confused on some point. Might as well create a function like this: `function checkForNullTermination(obj) { return true }`

Comment: You won't do this, unless you want to be sure that a current implementation of JS, has `null` at the bottom of the prototype chain. It might just be an interesting mental exercise.

Comment: If an implementation doesn't get prototype chains right, who's to say they'd get `Object.getPrototypeOf` right? The only proof would come from reading the implementation's source code.

Comment: Indeed. So I'd go with "It might just be an interesting mental exercise.".